# How to make this code to remove class name from items took getElementsByClassName and make this accordions work as I want them to?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to make a accordions using pure JS. And I'm in a half way.
I have three containers with texts and buttons. I want them to work in that way when I click on button -> paragraph next to it slide on the screen as accordion. And when you click another button it will happen to the next one, but if there was some open paragraph it will slide off/close.

I already make it to open - but when I click another one, if there is already opened one it will not close. I tried to make it alive with the code below:

````
<section class="accordions">
    <button class="accordion">Lorem ipsum</button>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas deleniti molestias necessitatibus quaerat quos incidunt! Quas officiis repellat dolore omnis nihil quo, ratione cupiditate! Sed, deleniti, recusandae! Animi, sapiente, nostrum?
      </p>
    </div>
    <button class="accordion">Lorem ipsum</button>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas deleniti molestias necessitatibus quaerat quos incidunt! Quas officiis repellat dolore omnis nihil quo, ratione cupiditate! Sed, deleniti, recusandae! Animi, sapiente, nostrum?
      </p>
    </div>
    <button class="accordion">Lorem ipsum</button>
    <div class="accordion-content">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas deleniti molestias necessitatibus quaerat quos incidunt! Quas officiis repellat dolore omnis nihil quo, ratione cupiditate! Sed, deleniti, recusandae! Animi, sapiente, nostrum?
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>```
````

```
let accordions = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");

for (let i = 0; i < accordions.length; i++) {
  accordions[i].onclick = function() {

    if (accordions.className === 'is-open') {
      for (let i = 0; i < accordions.length; i++) {
        accordions[i].classList.remove('is-open');
      }
    }

    this.classList.toggle('is-open');

    let content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {   
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```
But those opened paragraphs won't close themselfs. Cheers!
```

Comment: `className` returns a space-separated list of class names of an element, the condition checking for `is-open` class never passes on the elements collected based on `accordion` class.

Comment: Alternatively, don’t loop through _all_ elements all the time, but _remember_ the last opened element in a variable, and then only purposefully close that one, when you are about to open a different one …

Comment: So How can I take this last opened element to variable? I have no idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probelm was you were setting the maxHeight on sibling but not removing it on next Button click

```js
let accordions = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");

for (let i = 0; i < accordions.length; i++) {
  accordions[i].onclick = function() {

    for (let i = 0; i < accordions.length; i++) {
      
      /****************added lines********************/
      let content = accordions[i].nextElementSibling;
      if (content.style.maxHeight) {
        content.style.maxHeight = null;
      }



      accordions[i].classList.remove('is-open');


    }


    this.classList.toggle('is-open');

    let content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {

      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {

      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
  background: white;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-content {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 20px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<section class="accordions">
  <button class="accordion">Lorem ipsum</button>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas deleniti molestias necessitatibus quaerat quos incidunt! Quas officiis repellat dolore omnis nihil quo, ratione cupiditate! Sed, deleniti, recusandae! Animi, sapiente, nostrum?
    </p>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Lorem ipsum</button>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas deleniti molestias necessitatibus quaerat quos incidunt! Quas officiis repellat dolore omnis nihil quo, ratione cupiditate! Sed, deleniti, recusandae! Animi, sapiente, nostrum?
    </p>
  </div>
  <button class="accordion">Lorem ipsum</button>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas deleniti molestias necessitatibus quaerat quos incidunt! Quas officiis repellat dolore omnis nihil quo, ratione cupiditate! Sed, deleniti, recusandae! Animi, sapiente, nostrum?
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below should solve your problem:

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
              Collapsible Group Item #1
            </a>
          </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
              on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
              raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
              Collapsible Group Item #2
            </a>
          </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
              on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
              raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
              Collapsible Group Item #3
            </a>
          </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
            <div class="panel-body">
              Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird
              on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table,
              raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS-file:**

```
body {
  color: #6a6c6f;
  background-color: #f1f3f6;
  margin-top:30px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #e4e5e7;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a:after {
  content: "";
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  float: right;
  transition: transform .25s linear;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .25s linear;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  background-color: #eee;
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
  content: "\2212";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.panel-default>.panel-heading a[aria-expanded="false"]:after {
  content: "\002b";
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Comment: @Teemu Check out the updated answer, and let me know!!